# file upload not successful in online

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, apache, jakarta-ee

Here iam trying to upload images in to online this code works fine in local but it shows an exception while uploading online.i am using apaches coom file upload library and use eclipse as java editor any help.

**Exception:**

43832_1048_1.jpgThumbnails /var/www/kreativ/data/www/7.kreativwebsolutions.com/ROOT/Thumbnails/43832_1048_1.jpg
if::ListingURL Thumbnails `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/upload__63fd8030_144fd30231a__7ffb_00000022.tmp (No such file or directory)`

but i have a folder in my root directory.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
   <%@ page import="java.util.Iterator,java.util.*" %>
   <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload"%>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
   <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>      
   <%@ page import="java.awt.image. BufferedImage"%>    
   <%@ page import="javax.imageio.ImageIO"%>    
   <jsp:useBean id="EST" class="beans.estate_agent_table"/>
   <%
mainClasses.estate_agent_tableListing EST_CL = new mainClasses.estate_agent_tableListing();
List EST_List=EST_CL.getMestate_agent_table(session.getAttribute("AGENT_ID").toString());
if(EST_List.size()!=0){
       EST=(beans.estate_agent_table)EST_List.get(0);}
boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
boolean falg=true;
int movieimage_count=0;
String AGENT_REF="";
String moviealbum_id="";
String FileName=""; 
String sale_let="";
if (!isMultipart) {

}else{
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
       ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
       List items = null;
       try {
           items = upload.parseRequest(request);
           } catch (FileUploadException e) {
          out.print(e);
           }
       Iterator itr = items.iterator();
       while (itr.hasNext()) {
           FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
           if (item.isFormField())
               {
                  String name = item.getFieldName();
                  String value = item.getString();

                      if(name.equals("moviealbum_id"))
                              {  
                          moviealbum_id=value;

                              }

                      if(name.equals("movieimage_count"))
                      {  
                          movieimage_count=Integer.parseInt(value);

                      }
                      if(name.equals("propertyid"))
                      {  
                          AGENT_REF=value;                
                      }
                      if(name.equals("sale_let")){
                          sale_let= value;
                      }

               }else{
                   try{
                       String itemName = item.getName();

                       int dotPos = itemName.lastIndexOf(".")+1;
                       String extension = itemName.substring(dotPos);


                       if(extension.equals("JPG") || extension.equals("jpg") || extension.equals("gif") || extension.equals("GIF") || extension.equals("JPEG") || extension.equals("jpeg") || extension.equals("PNG") || extension.equals("png"))
                       {

                           movieimage_count=movieimage_count+1;

                      FileName=AGENT_REF+"_"+movieimage_count+"."+extension;

                       }
                       if(!FileName.equals(""))
                        {
                           try
                           {
                         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( item.getInputStream() );
                           beans.ResizeImage RI=new beans.ResizeImage();
                           BufferedImage thumb=RI.ReSize(image,80);
                           out.println(FileName+"Thumbnails");
                           if( EST.getThumbnails()==null || EST.getThumbnails().equals("null") || EST.getThumbnails().equals("")){
                           item.write(new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"Thumbnails/"+FileName));
                           out.println(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"Thumbnails/"+FileName+"if::ListingURL");
                           }else{
                               item.write(new File(EST.getThumbnails()+"Thumbnails/"+FileName));
                               out.println(FileName+"else::FileName");
                           }

                           }
                           catch(Exception es){out.print("Thumbnails "+es);}





                           try
                           {
                         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( item.getInputStream() );
                           beans.ResizeImage RI=new beans.ResizeImage();
                           BufferedImage thumb=RI.ReSize(image,80);
                           out.println(FileName+"list");
                           if( EST.getThumbnails()==null || EST.getThumbnails().equals("null") || EST.getThumbnails().equals("")){
                           item.write(new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"list/"+FileName));
                           out.println(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"list/"+FileName+"if::list");
                           }else{
                               item.write(new File(EST.getThumbnails()+"list/"+FileName));
                               out.println(FileName+"else::FileName");
                           }
                           }
                           catch(Exception es){out.print("Thumbnails "+es);}
                         }
                   }              
                   catch (Exception e) {
                       out.print(e);
                       falg=false;
                       }
               }



       }

}
%>
```

Comment: I assume you are using Linux, have you checked permissions in the tmp folder are you running your web server as root, tomcat or other user?

Comment: no i am using windows computer,but its a Linux server and ya iam running it as root,and about file permissions i have given read,write for the folder where i want the image to be placed, but not to the tmp folder..

Comment: Are you saying you have linux OS running? in that case try to chmod 777 * on that folder. safe if its non production, else look up other chmod safer permissions